# TransitionDrawable completed

Tags: android, animation, transition

I am running an animation in my Android app using the following code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.translate);
final TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) layout.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(9000);
```

The animation runs for 9 seconds, and then it needs to be reversed.

At the moment I am using a countdown timer (already one running in the app), to check if 9 seconds has gone by and manually reverse the transition....

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question, no there is no onCompletionListener. Instead you do have to manually count the seconds and then reverse the transision.

I also asked this question during an Android Developer Hangout with Google, and it could not be answered in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently come up against this problem and needed to transition between several images in a loop. I've posted an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612255/147180) with a custom class based on TransitionDrawable. It would be fairly simple to build callbacks into that class.

Hopefully this will help anyone else struggling with TransitionDrawables.

Comment: Recently I have changed from using TransistionDrawable to using ObjectAnimator. I then used Jake Wharton's NineOldAndroids (http://nineoldandroids.com/) to make it backwards compatible.