# Animating Drawable change in a Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-button, android-drawable

I have a `Button` that has a `BitmapDrawable` and a row of text in it. Not that it matter but my drawable is "above" my text which would correspond to the third button from the top.

[image: Examples of using setCompundDrawablesWithIntrisicBounds]

**The drawable is set using:**

```
BitmapDrawable top = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(buttonContent.content, 
            mContext.IMAGE_WIDTH, mContext.IMAGE_HEIGHT, false));

    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, top.getCurrent(), null, null);
```

The image that I set initially changes after some events and **I want the image change to be animated**. I already have the `android:animateLayoutChanges=true` field in my layout.

My initial guess is to create a custom `Button`-class. But I'm wondering if there's another way to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate the drawable itself. A [`TransitionDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) allows to cross-fade between layers (`setCrossFadeEnabled(true)`), you can start the transition by something like

```
((TransitionDrawable) button.getCompoundDrawables()[INDEX]).startTransition(MILLIS);
```

---

*Old answer based on `Animatable`s*: See the ["Drawable Animation" documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html). You can use that technique for compound drawables as well.

Start the animation using something like

```
((Animatable) button.getCompoundDrawables()[INDEX]).start();
```

or hold a reference to the `Animatable` when not setting the drawable from XML.

Comment: Looked at `AnimationDrawable` which is almost what I'm looking for. It isn't crossfading between the elements which is a bummer though

Comment: You probably want to use an [`TransitionDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) instead. A transition drawable is quite similar to an `Animatable`, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yep, that was sort of what I was looking for. Gonna mark it as an answer anyway :-) thanks

Comment: I'm getting this android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable

Answer (score 1):

The answer "dst" gave is correct. But if you're looking for a cross-fade animation between multiple images and don't want to use the `Animator`-classes ,the `TransitionDrawable` isn't gonna cut it. It's only for two images.

There's an answer to an almost similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033011/add-transition-to-an-animationdrawable/11612255#11612255). Check it out!