# Android: set drawable over button

Tags: android, button, layout, adt

in my app are 3 `Buttons` (screenshot at the bottom). Now I want to set an `AnimatedDrawable` (a finger) over the first `Button` (image at the bottom). I'm using a `LinearLayout` and the background of the Button is just a color (no drawable). 
I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/finger"></item>
</layer-list>
```

and set the `layer-list` as background of the `Button` but then the finger is as big as the `Button`. I also tried to use an `RelativeLayout` inside my `LinearLayout` but then I cant set the `weight` of the `Buttons`. I can't use an `ImageButton` because of the Text on the `Button`. So is there any possibility to manage that problem ?

Greetings Nils

[image: Like it is now (without the finger]

[image: Like I'd like it]

Comment: u have a option to set the hand image as button drawable and do the animation for drawable

Comment: use can use android:drawableRight=""for setting the hand button

Comment: Thanks, could you explain a bit more or post code? I don't understand your instructions.

Comment: pls check the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234613/animating-drawable-change-in-a-button

Comment: in yourlayout in the button add this line (sample code)android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"

Comment: Thanks, thats what i've searched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Instead of this "@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions" you can choose any image from drawable

Comment: I believe you mean "Instead" and not "Instant"

Comment: Thanks, I had to modify it setting the weight but works perfectly

Comment: What I've only just noticed is that the text on the is more left than without the image. Is it possible to solve that problem.

Comment: @user3125728 give padding and align that

Answer (score 0):

You can set image on button programatically by:

```
final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_Button);


btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
    }
});
```

You can use the "Image Button" it's better for you, and the code like this :

```
final ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.your_Button) ;
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/your_image");
next.enter.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Comment: But the problem is I can't set Text on an ImageButton