# Android: Load random images in crossfade to imageView

Tags: java, image, loops, random, imageview

I have this code but unfortunately it can only show two images and does not loop. I need a way to display 8+ images that change randomly to another with crossfades and is continuous. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I've mentioned:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

 class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Drawable backgrounds[] = new Drawable[2];
        Resources res = getResources();
        backgrounds[0] = res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
        backgrounds[1] = res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);

        TransitionDrawable crossfader = new TransitionDrawable(backgrounds);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageDrawable(crossfader);

        crossfader.startTransition(3000);

    }
}a
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but I was struggling with the same problem and wanted to show 4 images. Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11612255/2501621

This person has made a custom class based on Transition Drawable that can show any number of images. Works like a charm. Hope someone gets benefited from this answer.