# How can I automatically let my app transition between a set of images and start again from the first element?

Tags: java, android, transition

In my app I want the background in my menu to switch to another image, using a transition and cooldown. When all of the images in my array have been shown, I want a transition from the last element of my array to the first element and start all over.

Currently I'm using `TransitionDrawable`, but I don't know how to automate the process.

Below you can see my current code:

```
td = new TransitionDrawable( new Drawable[] {
            getResources().getDrawable(bgImages[0]),
            getResources().getDrawable(bgImages[1]),
            getResources().getDrawable(bgImages[2]),
            getResources().getDrawable(bgImages[3]),
            getResources().getDrawable(bgImages[4])
});

td.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);

td.startTransition(10000);

bg.setBackground(td);
```

Comment: Cant you use a `for` loop or any kind of loop for that matter?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: For some other functions in my menu it seems risky to put a for loop there, but I solved the problem with the AnimationDrawable. It's not perfect, cause it has no transition, but i can live with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033011/add-transition-to-an-animationdrawable this could be useful